# Safari on IOS ignoring CORS / not sending CORS preflight OPTIONS request

Tags: php, vue.js, mobile-safari, axios

I have a problem using Axios and VUEJS where I keep on getting an error `xmlhttprequest cannot load XXX due to access control checks` on Safari only.  The application works find on Chrome and Brave, but not Safari.

In addition, Safari seems to make a CORS request for the expected URL, but then cancels it without waiting for the response.

My endpoint is written in PHP

```
$origin = 'http://192.168.1.6:8080'; // For testing
$response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
$response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization,Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Range');
$response = $response->withAddedHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be due Safari not having previously defined CORS data for the website.  The API call in Axios was the result of a 302 response (I don't know if that is relevant) and for whatever reason it did not like that.

The solution was to add a ping request that established CORS (at least, that's what I think it's doing) when the application first loads.  Like this:

```
  this.$axios.get('api/ping').then(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('id_token')) {
      this.$router.push('/app/requests')
    }
  })
```

That ping, which just has an unauthenticated reply with CORS headers, allows subsequent API calls to execute just fine.